# How to load data file into database with C

Tags: mysql, c

I try to load local data file network.txt into a table network in mysql with C program. I do it like this, but it doesn't work. The error information is `mysql_query(&con, "load data local infile 'network.txt' into table network")`.

```
#include <mysql/mysql.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int 
main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    MYSQL           con;

    mysql_init(&con);
    if (mysql_real_connect(&con, "localhost", 
                    "hel", "password", "mydatabase", 0, NULL, 0) == NULL) {
        exit(0);
    }

    /* delete table network if it exists */
    if (mysql_query(&con, "drop table if exists network") != 0) {
        exit(0);
    }

    /* create table network */
    if (mysql_query(&con, "create table network(IP varchar(20), primary key (IP))") != 0) {
        exit(0);
    }

    /* load data file to table */
    if (mysql_query(&con, "load data local infile 'network.txt' into table network") != 0) {
        exit(0);               // ************error **************
    }
    mysql_close(&con);

    return 0;
}
```

**EDIT**==========================================================

I find `load data local infile 'network.txt' into table network` is shell command, not mysql command. Maybe this is the mistake.How can I load data file with C.

Answer (score 0):

Is the path to `network.txt` correct? Consider providing absolute path.

Comment: Yes, it's in the working directory. The problem is that `mysql_query(MYSQL *mysql, const char *stmt_str)` argument `stmt_str` can be mysql command, instead of `shell command`. But how can I load data file in C program.

Comment: Here is a similar answer for PHP: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16150401/mysql-load-local-data-infile. I do not think you need to load data file in `C` program. If it is in working directory, did you try using `./`?

Comment: Because I write the program in C, and needs to load a local file into database periodically. I try to input `load data local infile 'network.txt' into table network` in mysql shell, it succeeds. But in the C program with mysql_query, it fails. I don't know whether this function can use `load`  as the second argument or not.